# Placing exposed filters (with BEF) in various Panel regions

Tags: panels, views

So, my question is basically the same as [How to show in different positions exposed filters in a View?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/how-to-show-in-different-positions-exposed-filters-in-a-view)  However, the answer here did not work for me (and I could not post a comment there because I don't have 50 rep -- very sorry).  I follow the steps outlined exactly and I only have the option to place "View exposed widgets" with no sub options.

Basically, I'm trying to place my exposed filters in various places within the display (almost identically to the referenced ticket).  I'm running Views with type of Context and using Better Exposed filters.  According to quite a few places, that should allow me to place the individual filters in whichever region of the Panel I desire.  However, I don't see them.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

did you finally find a solution for this? You could use the module [MEFIBS](https://www.drupal.org/project/mefibs) which allows you to put your filters (and sort) into different blocks.

Anyway, MEFIBS didn't work for me because of the fact that all blocks get seperate submit button. So it would be interesting for me to hear how you finally ended up with this.

Best,
Thomas